# Edit cv showing experience in wrong order

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When you go to edit your cv in the jobs section shouldn't your work experience start from current to oldest?  Currently it shows me my most recent / current job at the bottom.  Should match the exported cv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the experience in any order you like with the up/down buttons on hover.

[image]

The order should match the PDF (it does as I'm looking at it now).

Comment: Looks good to me...My default order I guess was out of order.  I fixed it.